# Postgresql install adding openssl

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I install postgresql in my ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, and I want it support OpenSSL.

1. I do the lengthy way with PostgreSQL source code installation, where I can select the `openssl` feature:

```sql
 ./configure –with-openssl
  make
  make install
  ldconfigure
```

2. Upon installing the Ubuntu server I can select with the help of `tasksel` PostgreSQL to be installed, or using the `apt-get postgresql-10  postgresql-contrib`

Does the 2nd way configure PostgreSQL to add the feature of openssl (be SSL ready)?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK it does.  But why don't you just try it?  In any case, you will need a certificate, too - read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html

Comment: @dezso...I tried 1st & created crt for server & client. In chapter 16 if you install from  deb package it doesn't tell weather its pre configured or no.. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @dezsi...and it seems easy to install from deb rather than lengthy 1st way  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`pg_config` with --configure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgconfig.html) flag.

> ## `--configure`
>
> Print the options that were given to the configure script
>   when PostgreSQL was configured for building. This can be used to
>   reproduce the identical configuration, or to find out with what
>   options a binary package was built. (Note however that binary packages
>   often contain vendor-specific custom patches.)

And confirm whether the installed version has SSL enabled or not!

Comment: @hjpotter92...ok after fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server, then installling the postgresql-10 postgresql-server-dev-10 postgresql-client-10 & contrib & libpq-dev ..

Comment: @hjpotter92...I ran the pg_config command and the result in the question area up...what can you tell of that ?

Comment: @Mohd You see the `--with-openssl` flag in the output of the command? That means it was compiled with ssl support. :)